# WPF Generating Multiple ListViews at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to have something like this :

```
COMPANY A
EMPLOYEE 1 | ALBERT | EINSTEIN
EMPLOYEE 2 | ISAAC  | NEWTON
EMPLOYEE 3 | STEPHEN| HAWKING

COMPANY B
EMPLOYEE 1 | OBI-WAN | KENOBI
EMPLOYEE 2 | LUKE    | SKYWALKER
EMPLOYEE 3 | R2      | D2
```

I want to add companies on the fly programmatically at runtime, and bind them to objects that will change frequently.

PS : I really have *extremely* short dev delays (<1H) so I really have no time to familiarize with TreeView & MVVVM. I just need something ultra-basic, wimple, & stupid to start up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [WPF MDI](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/releases) with userControl ListViews created on different windows (1 by MDI window)

Answer (score 0):

That's a good idea.  You could also create a TabPanel and bind the list of "Companies".  (Tabs could be labeled with the name of the company for example.)  It should allow you to naturally layout your companies, and each of these tabs could contain a listbox that is bound the the tab's data context's employee list..... (Same complexity level as using MDI I imagine)

Also, if your data is well structured, you can relativly quickly create a HierarchicalDataTemplate and you could then bind it to a TreeView.  To be frank, if you only need to display your data, this might be your fastest bet.

But if you like your MDI environment, why change something that works! 
;-)

Comment: Thank you. TreeView has a very bad reputation and it frightens me as I really had no time to dig this for the moment. Concerning your answer, I have no Idea on how to create ListBoxes on the fly at runtime and add them (unless they are in usercontrols embedded in new windows. And tabbing is not very good in my case as I need to see all companies in one sreen.